# How to reset header buffer in Lucee?

Tags: unit-testing, cfml, lucee, testbox

I am trying to write a unit test for my ColdBox application running on Lucee 4.5 using [testbox](/questions/tagged/testbox) for a function that includes a [`cfhtmlhead()`](https://cfdocs.org/cfhtmlhead) call.

Unfortunately, the string that would normally be appended to the `<head>` section of the HTML output using that function is appended to the output of the unit test instead, causing the test to fail.

The output of `cfhtmlhead()` is obviously written to a special buffer. According to a [blog post](http://wwvv.codersrevolution.com/blog/Taming-The-Header-Output-Of-CFHTMLHead-and-CFAjaxProxy) it is possible to clear that buffer. The example function shown there looks like this:

```cfml
function clearHeaderBuffer() {
  local.out = getPageContext().getOut();
  while (getMetaData(local.out).getName() is "coldfusion.runtime.NeoBodyContent") {
    local.out = local.out.getEnclosingWriter();
  }
  local.method = local.out.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("initHeaderBuffer", arrayNew(1));
  local.method.setAccessible(true);
  local.method.invoke(local.out, arrayNew(1));
}
```

Though the blog post is written for Adobe ColdFusion and it obviously doesn't work the same way in Lucee.
By dumping `local.out` I saw that the object has a method `resetHTMLHead()`. But calling that method doesn't seem to work, either (even when the related `getHTMLHead()` method outputs the string from the `cfhtmlhead()` call).

So, how to reset the header buffer in Lucee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by checking the Lucee sources. There the [buffer is accessed via `getRootOut().getHTMLHead()`](https://github.com/lucee/Lucee/blob/0db6e70b53a870d4fcd750f4402a10bcfedaa701/core/src/main/java/lucee/runtime/tag/HtmlHead.java#L61).

So the code to clear the header buffer boils down to this:

```cfml
function clearHeaderBuffer() {
  getPageContext().getRootOut().resetHTMLHead();
}
```